# How to get sidenav from using bottom navigation bar in android?

Tags: android, navbar, sidebar

I want to develop an app where I will use bottom navigation bar and when user will choose the option item it would show the side bar like the following image that comes from either left or right side, but the option button will be in bottom navbar.

Navigation bar:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to create a Navigation View and bottom navigation bar.

NavigationView

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    android:layout_gravity="start"/>
```

Bottom Navigation Bar

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>
```

Now to open drawer you have to set your drawer layout (which will be the parent layout) inside setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener like this

```
bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
      when(it.itemId){
          R.id.your_bottom_menu_selected_id->{
                drawer_layout_id.openDrawer(navigationView)
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: i will not use any header layout in my navigation view.

so should i use drawer layout in that case?

Comment: Ya then just don't put header layout just define app:menu inside navigationView